# GzipOutputStream fails to serialise to a string using ProtoBuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to incorporate Protocol buffers in my project. I have created the following very simple schema:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Document{
    string title = 1;
    int64 size = 2;
    int64 data = 3;
}
```

Then in my C++ code (after compiling with the protobufc compiler) I use this as:

```
    Document document;
    document.set_title(random_string(20));
    document.set_data(300);
    document.set_size(500);

    std::string docString = document.SerializeAsString();

    std::string compressedString;
    google::protobuf::io::StringOutputStream stream(&compressedString);
    google::protobuf::io::GzipOutputStream gStream(&stream);
    document.SerializeToZeroCopyStream(&gStream);
    std::cout << docString.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << compressedString.size() << std::endl;
```

The output of the code above is:

> 28 0

Thus the compressed string is empty, while the normal string is 28. What is the correct way of using `GzipOutputStream` and compress the serialised data of a protocol buffer.

Comment: You probably need to `Flush` or `Close` the `GzipOutputStream`.

Comment: @idz thanks calling Flush does seem to be doing the trick. However, if I replace `StringOutputStream` with a `OstreamOutputStream` used with a `std::ofstream`, it seems that nothing is being written into the file.

Comment: my guess would be that that's the same issue... but now at a lower level. I suspect it does not complete writing until `OsteamOutputStream` goes out of scope. (I don't know if it has an explicit `Close` or `Flush`; if it does try calling that). I know `FileOutputStream` has a `Close` and I seem to recall it's use is preferred over `OstreamOutputStream` (more buffering).